# Custom Scopes using proxies in spring

Tags: spring, scope

Normally it is said that when you create your own scope, and Autowire a scoped object in your class,

It will inject the proxy object, and proxy object will call the method on the target bean.

So this means spring stores a list of object, and based on proxy's call it will give us the desired

object. Am i right? please explain

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that is said.  Spring does not create proxies for scoped beans by default (you have to ask for it, e.g. with ).  Once a proxy is created it is no different with a scoped bean than any other - the application context is a map from bean name to bean instance, and some of the beans are proxies.